# AngularJs: ngrepeat stepping through an ordered item

Tags: arrays, angularjs

I am new to Angular and web programming in general. I'm on a project for a client who's primary function is processing customer orders. The valet will be directed to a single page where there will be a service call that returns a customers specific order. A single order can obviously contain many items(and in this case these items can all be from different retailers I.E 1 item from amazon, 2 from ebay, etc.)

What I need to do is have a page iterate through the complete order and only display one item at a time. The valet will verify/place the order for that item, and then click 'next' to move on to the next item in the order until completion. I'm using ng-repeat and it displays the entire order, so my question is how would I limit it to a single item at a time? Is ng-repeat even the correct directive to use?

Thanks in advance for any help and let me know if I can clarify anything.

Comment: You could start by providing sample of what you have tried out. Even better, make a plunkr out of it.

Comment: So you are looking for some kind of "wizard" like navigation between the order items?

Comment: I'll work on a plunker tonight once I get home (asked question as I checked out for the day). But basically all I've done is wrap the entire page in a repeat that displays each item and its attributes (size, color, an image, etc) down the entire page. Been digging on google to no avail.
@Fedaykin: Essentially yes. They'll step through all the items, validating each.

Comment: Would you accept an answer, add more details or close the question altogether?

Answer (score 0):

I think that `ng-repeat` is not the answer, in that case you better iterate through your items using an index or even creating a `currentItem` on the scope and binding to it.

Since the first option is easier to demonstrate (but not the more elegant one) I made this plunkr: http://plnkr.co/edit/R1639k71qiCiOOoeGz84?p=preview

```
  <div ng-show="currentItemIndex < order.items.length">
      Item n. {{order.items[currentItemIndex].number}}<br/>
      Description<br/> 
      {{order.items[currentItemIndex].description}}<br/>
      <button ng-click="nextItem()">Next</button>
  </div>
```

Please take a look and see if that's what you are looking for, also, as a good exercise, fork that plunkr and make it work binding directly to a `$scope` variable so it can look like this:

```
  <div ng-show="currentItem">
      Item n. {{currentItem.number}}<br/>
      Description<br/> 
      {{currentItem.description}}<br/>
      <button ng-click="nextItem()">Next</button>
  </div>
```

See how that's much more easy to read? And also that allow you to maybe retrieve your order items from a server one by one, if that's ever the case, lol.

On your `nextItem()` you can add the required validation as well.

Hope that helps

Answer (score 0):

I'd say you have a long way to go if you want to make it elegant. Keep learning!

But if it's "working" you need, then here's quick example.

Assume your data in structured as

```
// order
{
  id: 1,
  items: [{
    id: 1,
    retailer: 'Amazon',
    name: 'Egg slicer',
    amount: 1,
    ordered: false
  },{
    id: 2,
    retailer: 'Gadget.com',
    name: 'Apple peeler',
    amount: 2,
    ordered: false
  },{
    id: 3,
    retailer: 'ZOMG!',
    name: 'Nose warmer',
    amount: 3,
    ordered: false
  }]
};
```

Then you could iterate and change state of each item back & forth using e.g.:

```
<h1>Verify order</h1>
<div>
  <div ng-init="current = 0; item = order.items[current]">
    <table class="table">
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th colspan="2">{{ item.retailer }}</th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <th>Item</th>
          <th>Amount</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        <tr>
          <td>{{ item.name }}</td>
          <td>{{ item.amount }}</td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
    <button ng-show="current > 0" ng-click="current = current - 1; item = order.items[current]">Back</button>
    <button ng-show="current >= 0 && current <= order.items.length" ng-click="order.items[current].ordered = !order.items[current].ordered">(De)select</button>
    <button ng-show="current < order.items.length - 1" ng-click="current = current + 1; item = order.items[current]">Next</button>
  </div>
</div>    
<hr />    
<div>
  <span>Ordered so far...<br /></span>
  <ul>
    <li ng-repeat="item in order.items | filter: { ordered: true }">
      {{ item.name }}
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Which yields

[image: imgur]

Related plunker can be found here http://plnkr.co/edit/ST9ki2